# Trying to write an XPath to extract the text ferrari referencing the 'Brand:' string

Tags: xpath

```xml
<dl class="do-ent-item">
    <dt class="do-ent-item">
        <span class="attr-name J-attr-name" title="Brand">Brand:</span>
    </dt>
    <dd class="do-entry-item-var">
        <div class="ellipsis" title="ferrari">ferrari</div>
```

I am trying to write an XPath to extract the text `ferrari` referencing the `Brand:` string above.

Comment: Share your `XPath`

Comment: What have you tried exactly? How did that fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you required to locate the element bases on brand . use following xpath

```
//span[@title='Brand']/../following-sibling::dd/div[@title='ferrari']
```

Explanation:

`//span[@title='Brand']`  - locate the tag contains brand

`/..` - navigate parent tag of context node

`/following-sibling::dd/div[@title='ferrari']` - will locate the sibling i.e `dd` tag which having the div with 'ferrari'

Answer (score 1):

For structure from the question you can use such xpath:

```
normalize-space(//dl[dt[contains(.,'Brand:')]]/dd)
```

It finds `dl` with `dt,`containg text `Brand:` anywhere in it, and returns full text of correspond `dd` tag - `ferrari` in the case